# Bibliography doesn't work -> missing item

Tags: bibliographies

My bibliography of my tex document doesn't work and I can't find out why.
I created 2 books in bibTex, but if I refer to them via

```
 %%% Main Document
    \bibliography{Seminar}
    \begin{thebibliography}
    \bibitem[Knuth98]{ComProgram} \emph{The Art of Computer Programming}
    \end{thebibliography}
```

The compiler says missing item on these lines. I did it just as in the tutorial in which I found these lines. The bib file is also in the same folder as the document.
I found many tutorials on google but I just don't seem to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the missing argument to `thebibliography`, which specifies the widest label:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{Knuth98}
```

Note. If you are using directly the `thebibliography` environment, the `\bibliography` command is useless.

Comment: oh i didnt know it was that simple, sorry for bothering you, but thanks a lot anyway

Comment: @dan Don't worry: I myself did sometimes the same mistake and scratched my head asking what was happening.